# Getting the wrong event from google calendar api

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Here is my current code:

```
Service = new CalendarService("googleid.apps.googleusercontent.com");
Service.setUserCredentials("calenderusername@gmail.com", "passwordforaccount");
var calendarquery = new EventQuery
      {
          Uri =new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/calenderusername@gmail.com/private/full"),
          StartTime = DateTime.Now,
          NumberToRetrieve = 1,
          SortOrder = CalendarSortOrder.@ascending
      };

      var feedItem = Service.Query(calendarquery).Entries.FirstOrDefault() as EventEntry;
      var times = new Google.GData.Extensions.When();
      times = feedItem.Times[0];
      var item = new CalendarEvent
      {
           Description = feedItem.Content.Content,
           EventDateStart = times.StartTime,
           Title = feedItem.Title.Text,
           EventDateEnd = times.EndTime,
           URL = feedItem.Links.FirstOrDefault().HRef.Content
      };
```

However, i get the item listed out:
EventStartDate: {10.02.2014 11:00:00}
EventEndDate: {10.02.2014 23:30:00}

But i know there is an event today(07.02.2014). Anyone have any idea what im doing wrong?

I'm confused wether to use startDate or startTime in my calendarQuery.

Comment: When exactly is the event today? If it's earlier than "now", that would explain why you couldn't see it. If you find all the entries based on `DateTime.Today`, do you see it? How about `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)` just out of interest?

Comment: The event starts at 1100 today, in 2~ hours. However, the weird thing is that it is another event tomorrow. Why would it skip to 10.02?

Comment: adddays-1 gives me {06.02.2014 11:00:00} actually. No idea why it would skip dates 07,08,09